# Fullcalendar add class to weekView

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I wanted to add a class like ".today-date" to the weekView Table Header in fullCalendar. **Because I wanted to highlight the Today Date Header with a background-color, like the td row is highlighted.**

The cell Content of the weekView already have a class ".fc-today .fc-state-highlight".

I try with dayRender function from fullcalendar, but my Javascript understanding is a bit to low... I hope someone can help the noob ;)

**My Html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.js"></script> 

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

**My Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
       defaultView: "basicWeek",
    });
});
```

**My Pen:** [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/angel_crawford/pen/zvJJRX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dayRender will work http://jsfiddle.net/6zq50vzc/3/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'basicWeek',
    dayRender: function(date, cell) {
        if (cell.hasClass('fc-today')) { // looking for today's cell
            var index = cell.index(); // get the td offset
            // find the corresponding item in header table
            var header = $('#calendar thead.fc-head th').eq(index);
            header.addClass('fc-today'); // update it with a class
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
viewRender: function(view, element) {
  if($('.fc-today').hasClass("fc-state-highlight")) {
    $('.fc-head .fc-head-container th').eq($('.fc-today.fc-state-highlight').index()).addClass("today");
  }
}
```

This will take the index of highlighted element and use that index to add a today class in header of calendar where day names are displayed.

Comment: It's always good to explain what your answer *actually does* when posting, this way OP can learn from it.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but i don't think it needs an explanation, it will the give same output as accepted answer, a different and shorter method that's all. anyway I am editing to explain working.